# show UIButtons one by one in a UIView

Tags: objective-c, animation

Hi I have a UIView which contains several buttons that are designed by others in Interface Builder. Now I need to show the buttons one by one with a 0.2 second delay, when the View is loaded.

Can someone give me some clue how I could implement this? e.g. in which method call what kind of animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do some research on NSTimers.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2f
             target:self
         selector:@selector(showSecondButton:)
         userInfo:nil
         repeats:NO];


-(void)showSecondButton:(id)sender{
    [button2 setHidden:NO];
}
```